# Can I specify a Celery Queue for every task in one of my Django Apps?

Tags: django, celery, django-apps

We currently have several Celery queues in our Django app. Right now we either specify a queue per task in our CELERY_ROUTES setting (if it isn't defined, it goes to a default queue), or in the task definition.

I'm launching a new django app within our overall project, and I'd like to dedicate a queue for all tasks in that app, not on a per task basis. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Really old question, but here it goes... From the documentation http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#id2, you can specify all tasks in tasks.py related to your app to use an specticic query:

```
task_routes = ([
('feed.tasks.*', {'queue': 'feeds'}),
('web.tasks.*', {'queue': 'web'}),
(re.compile(r'(video|image)\.tasks\..*'), {'queue': 'media'}),
],)
```

In your celery configuration file.